# Finding the first non-repeated character in a string

Tags: algorithm, regex, perl

Given a string, find the first non-repeated character in it.

E.g. "yellow" should return "y"

There are several solutions for this in other languages but I haven't seen one written in Perl.

My main question is: can this be done in a more Perl-ish way or generally in an even shorter way?

```
use strict;
use warnings "all";

while (<DATA>)
{
    while (m,(.),g)
    {
        my $c = $1;
        if (s,$1,,g < 2)
        {
            print "$c\n";
            last;
        }
    }
}

__DATA__
yellow
tooth
```

Comment: What should be output for string `aaabbc`?

Comment: @Tushar the output would be "c".

Comment: One way is to replace all repeating characters using regex `(.)\1*` and get the first character of the resulting string.

Comment: A nice solution but usage of `\1` is not advised I think. http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Warning-on-%5c1-Instead-of-%241

Comment: @yuri: `\1` must be used in the regex part, but in the replacement part you have to use `$1`.

Comment: `perl -E '$_ = "aabbbcd"; s/(.)\1+//g; /(.)/ && say $1' `

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't reinvent the wheel, there is a function (ie. `singleton`) in the package [`MoreUtils`](http://search.cpan.org/~rehsack/List-MoreUtils-0.419/lib/List/MoreUtils.pm#singleton) that does the job:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Modern::Perl;
use List::MoreUtils qw(singleton);

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;    # don't forget it, it removes the linebreak.
    # split explodes the string in character
    # singleton keeps characters that appear only once
    # ($first) contains the first character that appears only once.
    my ($first) = singleton split//, $_;
    say $first;
}

__DATA__
yellow
tooth
```

**Output:**

```
y
h
```

Comment: This is a nice solution but what if you work in an environment where you can't install extra dependencies?

Comment: @yuri: Inspect the module and copy the code of the function.